# Odd behavior with NSUInteger - can't convert to float properly

Tags: objective-c, c

Here is my situation. Its driving me nuts:

I have an NSMutableArray with a count value of 517. I have a double value that is my multiplier.

```
double multiplier = 0.1223;
double result = [myArray count] * multiplier; // 63 even (wrong!)
```

In fact it should be 63.2291. If I go:

```
double result = [myArray count] * 0.1223; // 63.2291 (right!)
```

or..

```
double result = 517 * multiplier; // 63.2291 (right!)
```

Does this make any sense to anyone?

Addendum:

here is my actual function:

```
- (double) getValueForPercentage:(double)percVal
{
   int adjustedCount = [originalData count] - 1;
   double final = percVal * (double)adjustedCount;
   return final;
}
```

I *never* get any digits beyond the decimal point when I do this. It *does* however work if I get rid of the "-1", a-la:

```
- (double) getValueForPercentage:(double)percVal
{
   int adjustedCount = [originalData count];
   double final = percVal * (double)adjustedCount;
   return final;
}
```

Of course, I need to have the -1.

Second addendum:

Another interesting thing I noted was, if I pass a hard-coded number to this function it works fine, but if I pass the double value that I need to use, it fails:

```
int pointCount = [srcData getDayCount];

for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; i++) {
   double progress = (double)i/(double)(pointCount - 1);
   double satv = [srcData getValueForPercentage:progress];
   // satv is always a number without any digits beyond the decimal
}
```

Comment: Interesting ... what's the result of `multiplier * [myArray count]`?

Comment: That works fine. Interesting addendum. In my actual function, there seems to be a fundamental issue with how I calculate multiplier because if I create a double any other way it works fine. When I inspect multiplier it looks fine.

Comment: I tried your code as written and was unable to duplicate your results. How are you calculating the multiplier?

Comment: Hey James, I've added an addendum to this. I oversimplified my original case.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on on your end. I just tried the exact same thing and it's working perfectly:

Comment: Hey guys I added some info. The way I call this function matters. I added the code I am using to call it.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum. I still can't figure it out (or replicate). Weird.

Comment: I agree that this should absolutely work. I must be missing something crucial. Going to take a break from things and come back to it fresh. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: The second addendum contains a danger if pointCount = 1.

Comment: Are you getting any missing declaration warnings?

Comment: what platform is this happening on? intel? ppc? arm?

Comment: Try long double.  It has more "room" then double, and it should suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when I started to have these issues i looked around a bit and found no reason or explanation.

What I do now is make everything become an NSNumber and then call doubleValue on it. This should yield the results you're looking for:

```
NSNumber * pointCount = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt: [srcData getDayCount]];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [pointCount intValue]; i++) {
    NSNumber * count = [ NSNumber numberWithInt: i ];
    double progress = [count doubleValue]/[pointCount doubleValue] - 1.0;
    double satv = [srcData getValueForPercentage:progress];
    // satv is always a number without any digits beyond the decimal
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Converting to NSNumber is the way to go. The class was written specifically to deal with these problems so that we don't have to.