# What are the result of multiplying NSUInteger by CGFloat?

Tags: ios, objective-c, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

What are the result of multiplying NSUInteger by CGFloat?

I think the result will be CGFloat.

```
- NSUInteger * CGFloat = - CGFloat
```

But actually the result gave an interesting manipulation. What rule should I know?

```
NSArray *arr = @[ @"One", @"Two", @"Three"];
NSLog(@"__float %f", - arr.count * 0.3f);
__float 1288490240.000000
```

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764874/odd-behavior-with-nsuinteger-cant-convert-to-float-properly
I am curious to know what happens if you do : (arr.count * 0.3f) * -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an order of operations question. The leading minus symbol is short for `-1 * ...`. This has the same priority as the multiplication `arr.count * 0.3f`. These are then executed from left to right. Trying to make an *unsigned* integer negative is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is that the change of sign is causing the unsigned integer representation to wrap-around.

If you change the sign of the float number, there is no problem:

```
NSLog(@"__float %f", - 0.3f * arr.count);
```

prints in screen __float -0.900000